# why aren't showing my product list in admin-products on angular from firebase

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular10

I'm following 'Mosh Hamadani'  for angular,and i am try to show title in my Form from firebase
As you can see try to show title in my form but i have this error:
**Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 16 in [product?.title=$event] in f:/Software/Angular10/oshop/src/app/admin/product-from/product-from.component.html@5:59ng**

```
I'm also try without ?. but it shows this error:
**core.js:5980 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
    at ProductFromComponent_Template (product-from.component.html:6)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9323)
    at refreshView (core.js:9192)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10358)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:8989)
    at refreshView (core.js:9242)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10312)
    at refreshView (core.js:9216)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10358)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:8989)**
```

**product-form.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
          <label for="basic-url"><b>Title</b></label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input #title="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="product?.title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
            </div>`enter code here`
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
                Title is required.
             </div>
              
            <label for="basic-url"><b>Price</b></label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">₹</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" #price="ngModel" (ngModel)="product.price" name="Price" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" required [min]="0"> 
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
              <div *ngIf="price.errors.required"> Price is required.</div> 
              <div *ngIf="price.errors.min"> Price should be 0 or.</div>
            </div>
            <label for="category"><b>Category</b></label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <select id="category" #category="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" class="custom-select" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.name">
                  {{c.name}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">
              Category is required.
            </div>
            <label for="basic-url"><b>Image Url</b></label>
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <input type="text" #ImageUrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.ImageUrl" name="ImageUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="ImageUrl" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required url>
              </div>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="ImageUrl.touched && ImageUrl.invalid">
                <div *ngIf="ImageUrl.errors.required">Image Url is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="ImageUrl.errors.url">Please input a valid url.</div> 
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" [src]="product.ImageUrl" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{product.title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{product.price | currency:'Rs:':true}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**product-form.component.ts**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from './../../Services/product.service';
import { CategoryService } from './../../Services/category.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {take } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-from',
  templateUrl: './product-from.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-from.component.css']
})
export class ProductFromComponent {
  categories$;
  product :any={};

  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private categoriesService:CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories$ = categoriesService.getCategories();
    
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if(id) {
      this.productService.getid(id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(p =>this.product = p);
     
    }
   }
  
save(product){
  this.productService.create(product);
  this.router.navigate(['/admin/products'])
 //console.log(product)
}

}
```

**product.service**

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product){
    return this.db.list('/product').push(product);
  }

  getAll(){
   return this.db.list('/product/').snapshotChanges();
  }

  getid(productId){
    return this.db.object('/product' + productId).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try product['title'] to display

Comment: yes i tried but still same error

Comment: Is it possible to create stackblitz

Comment: sorry i don't know how to create stackblitz

Comment: can you paste the sample of product, like JSON you are getting from service call